# Can't kick out hardcoded delay from my script to get the accurate result

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python selenium to collect some zip-code against few addresses from a webpage using reverse search. It's doing fine if i put a hardcodeed delay after each click. Although I've created my scraper using Explicit Wait, I could not get rid of this flaw. This happens only because as soon as the page loads, the zip code automatically updates according to the address I'm living and after clicking on a new search it takes 1/2 seconds for the new record to get placed. How can I kick out harcoded delay from my script and still get the flawless results?

Here is the link: [URL](https://www.mapdevelopers.com/what-county-am-i-in.php)

The script I've tried with:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

search_street =[
'43 Rue Caumartin',
'14 rue du Théatre',
'3 rue de Chevreuse',
]

def find_zip(driver, wait):
    for item in range(len(search_street)):
        driver.get("use_the_above_url")
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "address"))).send_keys(search_street[item],Keys.RETURN)

        time.sleep(2)  ##if i take out, the results get messy

        item_val = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"display_zip"))).text
        print(item_val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    try:
        find_address(driver, wait)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you get the initial value of the zipcode, and then wait for it to change? Also, you might want to wait for the page to finish rendering after you go to the page by waiting on the `document.readyState` variable.

Comment: What does "results get messy" mean? Do you get unexpected values, or do you get an error such as StaleElementException or something similar?

Comment: The results automatically gets update with the place I live in not with the search I'm after @Bryan Oakley. That Is what i tried to mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to iterate through list of streets and wait until zip-code value changed on each iteration:

```
for street in search_street:
    driver.get("https://www.mapdevelopers.com/what-county-am-i-in.php")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    zip_id = "display_zip"
    current_item_val = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(zip_id).text)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "address"))).send_keys(street, Keys.RETURN)
    wait.until(lambda driver: current_item_val != driver.find_element_by_id(zip_id).text)
    item_val = driver.find_element_by_id(zip_id).text
    print(item_val)
```

Comment: What if two sequential addresses have the same zip? I would wait for the element containing the zipcode to go stale, then you know the page has at least started to reload before scraping the new zip.

Comment: It's always a great pleasure to hear from you @ sir Andersson. I executed your code but it gives me the default zip code which i was having earlier if hardcoded delay was taken out. To be specific: I'm having the zip code the exact city i live in not the one i search for.

Comment: @Topto, I'm not sure I correctly understood the issue and can reproduce it exactly as you do... Zip-code initially is empty, right? Then after you enter the city name and confirm input it changed to your own zip for a moment and then it changed to correct zip?

Comment: No sir, not that really. Zip code is initially empty, that's true. When I input an address then I'm supposed to get only the correct zip code for my search but before displaying the correct one there is a microsecond pause in between when the default zip code shows up and vanishes. However, the script is always catching the zip code appearing for a short while between each search.

Comment: Check out the link sir. I've somehow caught the picture. In the address bar I've typed some address and before pressing the search button the zipcode field has got already filled in with the wrong one: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9zfzpsdao9kup5/Untitled.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @Topto, Check updated and let me know if issue still persist. Note that app seem to work differently from my side, so I cannot be sure in current solution :)

Comment: @JeffC, the problem is that after page loaded and OP entered city name in input field the value of zip-code field changes as *no text* -> *local zip* -> *target zip*, so we need to catch the moment when *local zip* replaced by *target zip*. Element itself will not be stale, so `EC.staleness_of` is not an option in this case

Comment: No way. This is what is supposed to happen when you intervene @ sir Andersson. Just a matter of time. Although, you have provided sufficient explanation, utmost request to you to give another line of detailing as to what you did. Thanks sir for everything.

Comment: So I looked at this some more and what I found is that if you load the page and do nothing, it finds your address and that's where the OP's zip is coming from. What I did was to load the page and wait until the zip was not empty, then I sent the address, then I waited for the zip to change. The only thing I think you are still missing is that initial wait for the zip to be not empty to be extra safe.